# How to select different boxes with key UP/DOWN/RIGHT/LEFT?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

This code snipets shows 3x3 matrix where I can hover and select boxes. I want to move around with keys and select some `box` with ENTER. How can I do that?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
   .box{
   background-color:rgb(100,12,120);
   height: 100px;
   width:100px;
   transition: transform .6s;
   }
   .box:hover{
   transform: scale(1.1);
   background-color:rgb(200,150,120);
   }
   .active {
   background-color: rgb(100,150,255);
   color: white;
   }
</style>
<div class="container m-5" id="myDIV">
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-around m-3">
      <div class="box "></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-around m-3">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box active"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-around m-3">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
   // Get the container element
   var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   
   // Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
   var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("box");
   
   // Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
   for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
     btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
       var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
       current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
       this.className += " active";
     });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: You can add this logic via a [keydown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event).

Comment: You forgot to add the code necessary to at least use the key events and some algorithm to navigate a 2D matrix. What have you tried? Please read [ask], then [edit] with your best [mcve]. PS: On keydown - check for the `Event.key` starts with `/^Arrow[UDLR]/.test(evt.key)` - If up or down change the index for `y` else change it for `x`. If you want it to loop over the X or Y axis then make sure to fix for indexes  being `-1` or  column/row.`length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WARNING**: You can go to the next row if you are at the end of a row, and you click `ArrowRight`. Same for `ArrowLeft`, start of row and you go to the previous one.

#### Full demo

```js
// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myDIV");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("box");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].classList.remove("active");
    this.classList.add("active");
  });
}

// On arrow click
onkeydown = event => {
  var activeNumber, originalActiveNumber;
  // Get the active button index
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    if (btns[i].classList.contains("active")) {
      originalActiveNumber = activeNumber = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowUp":
      activeNumber -= document.querySelectorAll("#myDIV > div").length;
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      activeNumber += document.querySelectorAll("#myDIV > div").length;
      break;
    case "ArrowLeft":
      activeNumber--;
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      activeNumber++;
      break;
  }
  if (activeNumber >= 0 && activeNumber < btns.length) {
    btns[originalActiveNumber].classList.remove("active");
    btns[activeNumber].classList.add("active");
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: rgb(100, 12, 120);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: transform .6s;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background-color: rgb(200, 150, 120);
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(100, 150, 255);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container m-5" id="myDIV">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around m-3">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around m-3">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box active"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around m-3">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const boxContainer = document.getElementById('myDIV')

const selected = {
  row: 2,
  column: 2,
}

const Clamp = (num, min, max) => Math.min(Math.max(num, min), max)

const ActivateSelection = (prev) => {
  const box = boxContainer.querySelector(`.boxGroup:nth-child(${selected.row}) .box:nth-child(${selected.column})`)

  box.classList.add('active')

  if (!prev) return
  if (prev.row === selected.row && prev.column === selected.column) return

  const prevBox = boxContainer.querySelector(`.boxGroup:nth-child(${prev.row}) .box:nth-child(${prev.column})`)

  prevBox.classList.remove('active')
}

const OnKeyDown = event => {
  const maxRow = boxContainer.querySelectorAll('.boxGroup').length
  const maxCol = boxContainer.querySelectorAll(`.boxGroup:nth-child(${selected.row}) .box`).length

  const prevBox = { ...selected }

  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowUp":
      selected.row = Clamp(selected.row - 1, 1, maxRow)

      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      selected.row = Clamp(selected.row + 1, 1, maxRow)

      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      selected.column = Clamp(selected.column + 1, 1, maxCol)

      break;
    case "ArrowLeft":

      selected.column = Clamp(selected.column - 1, 1, maxCol)
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }

  ActivateSelection(prevBox)
}

const GetActive = () => {
  const active = {}
  boxContainer.querySelectorAll('.boxGroup').forEach((el, index) => {
    el.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach((el2, index2) => {
      if (el2.classList.contains('active')) {
        active.row = index + 1
        active.column = index2 + 1
      }
    })
  })

  if (active.row) return active

  return undefined
}

ActivateSelection()

window.addEventListener('keydown', OnKeyDown)

boxContainer.querySelectorAll('.boxGroup').forEach((el, index) => {
  el.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach((el2, index2) => {
    el2.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const prev = GetActive()

      selected.row = index + 1
      selected.column = index2 + 1

      ActivateSelection(prev)
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: rgb(100, 12, 120);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: transform .6s;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background-color: rgb(200, 150, 120);
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(100, 150, 255);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container m-5" id="myDIV">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around m-3 boxGroup">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around m-3 boxGroup">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around m-3 boxGroup">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```